# SUM over datedifference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have the following records with column datetime

| dtTime | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 19:21:52.293 | 1 |
| 2020-12-10 19:21:52.323 | 2 |
| 2020-12-10 19:21:53.293 | 1 |
| 2020-12-10 19:21:58.293 | 1 |
| 2020-12-10 19:21:59.193 | 1 |

How can I make this to return rows that are in range of let's say 1.5second of eachother in the same rownumber? So sum the group by over:

| Row_Number | dtTime | qauntity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-10 19:21:52.293 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-12-10 19:21:52.323 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-12-10 19:21:53.293 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-12-10 19:21:58.293 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-12-10 19:21:59.193 | 1 |

So desired sum result:

| Row | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |

To clarify further based on the comments:
The situation is that there is a trigger, which will insert 10 to 20 records. The difference between dtTime of record 1 and record 20 will be MAX 2 seconds. The time interval between trigger 1 and trigger 2 will always be bigger than this 2 seconds.
I hope this claries the question on how to group!

Comment: Sounds like you want `DENSE_RANK` not `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specifiy I had to sum, but the row number was an illustration of which rows to sum, based on time difference

Comment: The desired result is *not clearly defined*. If you have `dtTime` like 19:21:51, 19:21:52, 19:21:53, 19:21:54, 19:21:55, 19:21:56 the you can group (and create sums) in different ways:  (19:21:51, 19:21:52), (19:21:53, 19:21:54), (19:21:55, 19:21:56) OR 19:21:51, (19:21:52, 19:21:53), (19:21:54, 19:21:55), 19:21:56.

Comment: I agree with @cars10m you should provide what grouping you want. Please add for example 2020-12-10 19:21:51.053 and explain in which group it should be added? Is it grouped with 2020-12-10 19:21:53.293 even is between these two dates more than 2 seconds or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define the groups:

```
select min(dttime), max(dttime), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_dttime > dateadd(millisecond, -1500, dttime) then 0 else 1 end) over (order by dttime) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(dttime) over (order by dttime) as prev_dttime 
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4ad4d26345eb39a1ddefd842e8d2c3a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure why but this just returns 1 record in which all records are summed.

Comment: @vincentkleine . . . I fixed two typos and added a db<>fiddle.